# Getting NULL value in Controller Object while passing POST Object using Jquery Ajax

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I am trying to post html form data to .net core Controller Using Ajax Post. I am storing form data inside a Js Object and sending POST request to Controller using Ajax but I'm getting a null value int the controller object.

HTML Code

```
<div class="container">
    <form id="employeeForm">
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label asp-for="FullName" class="form-label">Full Name</label>
            <input type="text" asp-for="FullName" placeholder="Full Name" class="form-control" required>
            <input asp-for="Id" hidden />
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label asp-for="Address" class="form-label">Address</label>
            <input type="text" asp-for="Address" placeholder="Address" class="form-control" required>
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label asp-for="PhoneNo" class="form-label">Phone Number</label>
            <input type="text" asp-for="PhoneNo" placeholder="Phone Number" class="form-control" required>
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label asp-for="Department" class="form-label"></label>
            <input type="text" asp-for="Department" placeholder="Department" class="form-control" required>
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <a class="btn btn-success" onclick="addEmployee()">Save</a>
            <a class="btn btn-danger" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="EmployeeList">Cancel</a>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

JS Code

```
addEmployee = () => {
    if ($('#employeeForm').valid()) {
        
        var obj = {
            FullName: $('#FullName').val(),
            Address: $('#Address').val(),
            PhoneNo: $('#PhoneNo').val(),
            Department: 0
        }
        debugger;
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Home/AddEmployee',
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/xxx-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8;',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: obj,
            success: function (res) {
                alert(res);
            },
        });
    }
   
};
```

C# Controller Code

```
public class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public int Department { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNo { get; set; }
}

[HttpPost]
public JsonResult AddEmployee(Employee obj)
{
        return Json("hello");
}
```

[Also, I have tried running it in debugging the post request send request to controller but with null data.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VucFg.png)

Comment: Can you check the values of `FullName , Address..` using `console.log($('#FullName').val())` in your browser element tab ?

Comment: Yes it returns value. Console.Log(obj)
{FullName: 'wqfgqg', Address: 'qwgefqg', PhoneNo: '01-1232435 , 9172948719', Department: 0}

Comment: @BishalRajParajuli  in your form html I am unable to see id's `FullName,Address...etc`. So how's you are getting values?

Comment: I have used Razor Pages of ASP.net core so adding "asp-for" inside a Input Tag which will denoted as Id in HTML.

Comment: `xxx` - Freudian slip?

Answer (score 0):

You use the incorrect content type, change like below:

```
contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
```

Comment: Thank you but removing the contentType solved my problem.

Comment: Hi @BishalRajParajuli, They are the same.... if you remove the contentType, it will set default contentType `"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"`. So your main issue is because you misspell the contentType value...

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem could be with your js code. According to [ASP .NET Core Web API Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio#test-posttodoitem), you might need change your content type to application/json in order to send Employee object over the wire.

```
addEmployee = () => {
if ($('#employeeForm').valid()) {
    
    var obj = {
        FullName: $('#FullName').val(),
        Address: $('#Address').val(),
        PhoneNo: $('#PhoneNo').val(),
        Department: 0
    }
    debugger;
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Home/AddEmployee',
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json;',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: obj,
        success: function (res) {
            alert(res);
        },
    });
}
```

};

Comment: Thank you but removing the contentType solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer removing the **contentType** in ajax will solve the problem.

```
addEmployee = () => {
if ($('#employeeForm').valid()) {
    
    var obj = {
        FullName: $('#FullName').val(),
        Address: $('#Address').val(),
        PhoneNo: $('#PhoneNo').val(),
        Department: parseInt($('#Department').val())
    }
    debugger;
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Home/AddEmployee',
        type: 'POST',
        //Remove Content Type
        //contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            obj: obj
            },
        success: function (res) {
            alert(res);
        },
    });
}
```

This has solved my problem.